# Uniqueness of $\delta$-structure on a $p$-torsion ring

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, p-adic-hodge-theory, perfectoid-spaces

I was working through Bhargav's notes on $\delta$-rings and prismatic cohomology, specifically [lecture 2](http://www-personal.umich.edu/%7Ebhattb/teaching/prismatic-columbia/lecture2-delta-rings.pdf), page 2, point 5 where he claims that the ring $\mathbb Z[x]/(px,x^p)$ has a unique $\delta$-structure given by $\delta(x) = 0$.

While it's easy to verify that this is a $\delta$ structure, I don't see why it has to be unique. In fact, isn't $\delta(x) = x$ also a $\delta$-structure? (At the level of the Frobenius, they are the same).

In general, what is the easiest way to check or define a $\delta$-structure?

Comment: The notes don't say $\delta$ is unique, it says there is a unique $\delta$-structure such that $\delta(x) = 0$.

Comment: @NicolasHemelsoet You are certainly right, but it's true that the sentence is slightly ambiguous. I'm not a specialist, but if I did not make a silly mistake the $\delta$-structures on that ring are exactly those given by $\delta(x) =$ a polynomial with zero constant term.

Comment: @aurel that's what I got too. hmm. That's slightly confusing wording!